# What is the relation between restoring force and maclaurin series?

Tags: euler-maclaurin

I have seen in some of the books any kind of restoring force can be expressed in maclaurins series about the equilibrium position. And they always seem to pick the second term as the first one is equilibrium and the rest are negligible. I dont really understand the significance behind it.

Comment: Restoring force - as in physics? Would you have an example problem where this is used?

Comment: At equilibrium the first (linear) term vanishes.

Comment: Like restoring force due to hookes law